# C++ динамическое выделение памяти

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос почему память после оператора delete память так и остается задействована или я что то не так понимаю:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int *p=new int[10];

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

       p[i]=i;

     }
     delete [] p;//удаление массива

      cout<<p[2];//и после удаления почему то благополучно выводится значение

         }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Про то, как надо удалять массивы, Вам уже написали. Напишу про то, почему сохраняется доступ к старым данным.

Даже если правильно удалять динамически выделенную память, то не всегда из кучи выгружаются подключенные страницы памяти, особенно если они в середине кучи. Просто они в помечаются как свободные и при повторном запросе на выделение памяти могут быть использованы, если хватает объема. Это ускоряет процесс динамического выделения памяти, которые является довольно ресурсоемким.

Comment: Ясно, я думал что это память уже не используется, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: На самом деле, может и выгружаться, если ее много (больше размером страницы) и она расположена в конце кучи. Тут все зависит от стандартной библиотеки.

Answer (score 6):

Во-первых вы не правильно выполняете удаление массива - надо удалять так

```
delete [] p;
```

Во-вторых, после освобождения памяти, содержимое обычно не очищается, просто участок помечается как свободный. Поэтому там могут некоторое время сохранятся старые значения.

Comment: Опечатка вышла, я и имел в виду delete [] p; а как мне удалить безвозвратно?

Comment: Сначала обнулите все ячейки памяти, например с помощью функции memset, а потом выгружайте delete'ом. Только зачем это нужно?

Comment: А вы там что-то секретное храните? Можно перед удалением нулями забить.

Comment: Обнуленная ячейка не использует память?

Comment: Использует и обнуленная и удаленная, просто удаленная в будущем **может быть** повторно использована (другим new).

Comment: Рекомендуют также после delete [] p; Использовать р = 0; Тогда повторный delete (по забывчивости) не сулит неприятностей.

Comment: В деструкторе класса и в том месте, где указатель выходит за область видимости, можно и не обнулять, потому что к этому указателю нельзя уже будет обратиться.

Comment: @skegg, компилятор имеет право удалить вызов memset если заполненния память не используется. И он так и поступит. Нельзя затирать секретные данные при помощи memset.

Answer (score 4):

То, что создается с помощью new[], должно удалятся с помощью delete[]. Иначе будут утечки.
А то что значение выводится - это компилятор не досмотрел и не дал по пальцам, а вообще то должно было б сгенерироваться исключения доступа к памяти  (хотя в релизных вариантах не объязательно).

То есть, то что Вы обратились к памяти, которую освободили и там что то вывелось - это просто UB (неопределенное поведение). В приведенном выше примере ничего плохого скорее всего не будет, а вот в какой нибудь нагруженной системе может вывестись совсем другое значение (в лучшем случае).

Comment: Опечатка, исправил.

Comment: ....в худшем случае - конец света, если система разработана для всемирной сети атомных станция =)

Comment: @KoVadim, а где Вы видели исключение по доступу к памяти (по простому SIGSEGV) при обращении к памяти, освобожденной по delete (или free) ?

Назовите систему, пожалуйста.

Comment: О SIGSEGV никто я не говорил. Под словом "исключение" я понимал более общий вариант. Никто не мешает использовать различные специализированные менеджеры памяти для отслеживания обращений к освобожденной памяти. В VisualStudio C++ компилятор может заполнять память специальными значениями для отслеживания подобных обращений.

Comment: >То, что создается с помощью new[], должно удалятся с помощью delete[]. Иначе будут утечки.

 Я видел в книге Борескова "Расширения OpenGL" такую ошибку, когда он выделял память для изображения через new[], а удалял через delete. Причём, не где-нибудь один раз, а везде.

Answer (score 1):

После завершения программы вся занятая память все равно освободится, так, что на это счет можно особо не париться. А вообще будьте осторожнее, здесь, в вашем коде по нелепой неосторожности может произойти утечка памяти.

Comment: >После завершения программы вся занятая память все равно освободится, так, что на это счет можно особо не париться.

 Это считается плохим тоном программирования. Потом что-нибудь изменишь, программа разрастётся, а удалить забудешь.

Comment: Ну это в линейных, простых алгоритмах типа разбиения строк и т.д.
В сложных системах, использующие паттерны, конечно за эти нужно следить.